# IntelliJ editor code style setting for spaces within parentheses defining a Records class (JEP 359: Records (Preview)) in Java 14?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, record, code-editor, java-record

I am using IntelliJ 2020.1.1 RC, which is supposed to have support for Records feature being previewed in Java 14. (See [JEP 359: Records (Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359))

I cannot find a setting to put spaces within the parentheses of the class definition for a `record`.

Example code:

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalTime;

public record LocalTimeRange(LocalTime start , LocalTime stop)
{
}
```

Screen shot of IntelliJ preferences for Java code style.

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ preferences for Java code style]

Comment: Formatter for Records [is work in progress](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229706). A [feature request is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Do you want to make that an Answer for me to accept?

Comment: I'd submit a specific request to YouTrack and link it from the answer.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Looks to me like # 1 item in your linked [ticket # IDEA-229706](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229706) already covers my case here. Would opening another ticket help? Seems redundant.

Comment: If it covers your case, then it's fine, you can just leave a comment with an example of the desired formatting.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks. Done. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work in progress, follow this YouTrack ticket for updates:

- [IDEA-229706](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229706) Formatter for Java 14 Records